# How determine/guess the OS of a webserver?

Tags: html, w3c

I want to determine or guess the underlying OS a website, for example stackoverflow.com, is using.

I have searched multiple statistic websites, but the OS question is answered by few and if, they provide only a general summary, e.g. "50% of ll websites use ...", and no website-individual information.

I Expect there must be some kind of guess based on the HTML-code probably, that allows for that conclusion. I kindly ask for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML doesn't tell you anything at all about the underlying server or OS.  It isn't a useful fingerprinting method unless you were to know that a certain type of web application only ran on a particular OS.

The web server will often identify itself in the HTTP response headers.  This sometimes contains OS information.  However, this information is self-reported and can be changed by anyone.

Beyond that, certain systems often have certain quirks in how they behave, which can be used for fingerprinting.  For example, a malformed request may result in a certain error page that can be used for identification.

See this project for more examples:  https://github.com/scipag/httprecon-nse

Finally, note that any sort of fingerprinting isn't 100% accurate.  Most fingerprinting relies on a certain default configuration that can be changed.  It's also possible to emulate another system.

You really can't know with certainty what OS a server is running.